# Best way to store Excel Rows with different columns related to each other?

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, data-structures, apache-poi

I'm reading an Excel file with an arbitrary number of columns and rows using Java. The first two columns are irrelevant, but the following columns (in pairs of two) refer to *data-entities attributes*. Each Entity is related to each other, so, for example, I can refer Cell E1 and get the data from Cell M1.

Which data structure should I use for this case? I'm using Apache POI to read from the Excel file, by the way.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I stored each column as an Object and put a list/map of column data in each column class. Then I would be able to get each cells data by referring to the `column.list` at the _nth_ position. I don't know if this is the best way of doing this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a header row and your headers are unique, store each row as a Map where the key is the header and the value is the cell text. This adds context to your data and makes your row data structure meaningful and able to be used without passing around a mapping from column number to header name alongside your row data structure (probably a List at this point) to other consumers. This does come at the cost of speed and memory, though.

Depending on how you interpret your data, you could include or exclude entries from the map when a cell is empty/blank. You then would use a List to organize all these rows.

If your data structure needs to know the cell address (or numeric row and column), but you can't just pass an XSSFSheet object around (either to hide the fact that you're using POI from the rest of your application or you can't keep the XLSX file open due to memory), use either a List or a Map to organize the rows. The Map would be better if there are a bunch of blank rows that you don't want to save a bunch of null values in your list to keep the list index and row number consistent. The row data structure could be a List where the index is the column number of the cell, a Map if your columns are sparse.

Another route you could go if you wanted to bundle your header and cell text together is to use a kind of tuple or Pair (such as org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair). These could be stuffed into a List or Map.

You definitely want to consider what your consumers of this data structure are and how you can optimize the structure to minimize searching through your data structure to pull out the correlations.
Maybe a plain old `String[][]` will work...

Have you taken a look at java.sql.ResultSet yet? It sounds like your data follows a relational database table structure.

If you had an upper bound or a fixed number of columns, I would have recommended a tuple or a namedtuple to store your row contents but it sounds like your data is more freeform than that.